# summation of reciprocal of factorial and square root

Tags: summation, factorial

Is it possible to get an analytical expression as a function of the positive real number $a>1$ for

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!\sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: Mathematica returns no closed form expression so I would assume not